# What does an operating system need to have to be considered a Linux distro?

Tags: linux, assembly

Let's say I wanted to create a version of Linux that ran on a WDC 65C02 CPU. How is Linux "defined?" What criteria need to be met for an operating system to be considered Linux rather than just "some other homebrew OS?" I plan on writing this in assembly directly, as I find code generated by cc65 to be somewhat inefficient.

Comment: Linux is a kernel. So to be linux it needs to use the linux kernel. Userland can vary - but generally is gnu, but can be freebsd. If you wrote the OS in assembly directly it won't be linux

Comment: What if I used a C compiler then manually reviewed the output and optimized it?

Comment: @puppydrum64 It's irrelevant. If it uses the Linux kernel, it's a distribution of Linux. Linux is the kernel, not the OS, and the common way of referring to the OS as "Linux" is confusing enough to have [a related Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux_naming_controversy)

Comment: @gronostaj Oh, yeah, the GNU/Linux copypasta.

Comment: So if I compiled the Linux Kernel for a 6502 it would count?

Comment: I know it's a meme, but it's also a legitimate discussion. There's a very specific product called "Linux" and then there's a very broad family of OSes based on the original Linux that are also being referred to as "Linux" despite only having it as one of its (key) components

Comment: The problem is with the definition of "*distro*". The common expectations from a Linux distro by an enduser is ease of installation, a selection of installable packages, and maintenance updates. So a Linux kernel with a minimal root filesystem (e.g. just Busybox) presumably qualifies as a "Linux OS", but IMO fails as a "Linux distro", especially if only used personally and never distributed to anyone else.

Comment: "*Let's say I wanted to create a version of Linux that ran on a WDC 65C02 CPU*" -- The  Linux kernel was originally written for a 32-bit processor with MMU. Good luck trying to get it to work on an 8-bit micro and no MMU. Yes, there's a variation of Linux for uP w/o MMU, but 32-bit wordsize is still expected.

Comment: @sawdust Having a kernel with a minimal amount of userland utilities, just enough to configure network interfaces and load iptables sounds like a perfectly valid distribution. Useful with a well-defined purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Linux" is the trademark of **one specific product** (an OS kernel), not a standard or a specification. Unlike e.g. "UNIX", there is no process for certifying an OS as "Linux" even if it reaches 100% compatibility with it.

In other words, an OS kernel written from scratch would not be Linux by definition (in the same way that ReactOS is not Windows, even though it is a Windows-compatible OS), although an OS kernel with clear lineage from the "[mainline](https://kernel.org/)" Linux source code may still be called Linux to some extent. The ELKS kernel for the 8086 CPU was originally a fork of Linux but very quickly diverged to the extent that it only calls itself a "Linux-like" kernel.

An OS would be considered a "Linux distribution" if it uses the Linux kernel. Android could be called a Linux distribution (though it's a bit of a stretch) because it still runs on the Linux kernel, while Debian/kFreeBSD or Debian GNU/Hurd are not Linux distributions because they don't include the Linux kernel (even though they include everything else that Debian Linux has).

Comment: Your repeated use of "*OS kernel*" is problematic. Calling Linux simply a kernel should suffice. When you add userspace support (with a root filesystem) then you have an operating system. IMO when you further add distribution and maintenance support, then you have a "distro".

Comment: Have you heard about Linux Standard Base specification?

Comment: @Anixx: I have; I don't see its relevance.